# Transferring a hash between form and URL

Tags: php, urlencode

Each user has a hash of their id to allow me to initiate connections between them.

So, a user gets a request to connect and they fisrtly get a link with the hash of the user wanting to connect (connectID is the hash)

e.g.

```
connect.html?connectID=8W7SBvYj7fnpu4+S4=
```

So I urlencode this to then arrive at a form. I am storing the value of connectID in the form in a hidden field but when I look at the source the form shows the hidden field has a value of

```
<input type="hidden" name="connectId" value="8W7SBvYj7fnpu4 S4="> (space where + was)
```

I've tried urlencode on the hidden field but this doesn't make any difference, if I view the source it's still the same

How can i overcome this and keep it the same as it was when it started travelling between URLs and forms?

I need it to match exactly as when it arrives at the final processing section of the process I check it against the hash stored for the user in the Mysql db

Comment: if it was urlencoded properly, the field value would have a `%2B` instead of `+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried urlencode on the hidden field

You have to encode the data before putting it into the URI, not after taking it out of the URL

```
$uri = "connect.html?connectID=" + urlencode('8W7SBvYj7fnpu4+S4=');
```